# Restricting the windows 8 app to view in portrait mode(WinRT)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

In my application, the landing view only support portrait view all the other views support both portrait and landscape views. So here my requirement is i need to restrict my landing page to display only in portrait view and all the other views support both. How i can achieve this in windows 8 / WinRT.

Comment: Here is the answer from msdn forum
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/82c199a0-57b1-49fe-a706-3e88b8e5148b

Answer (score 2):

[Disable or prevent a Page from Portrait Mode in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807726/disable-or-prevent-a-page-from-portrait-mode-in-windows-8/16808286#16808286)

see this, it may be helpful. It is for disabling portrait mode in specific pages.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I got result from here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/82c199a0-57b1-49fe-a706-3e88b8e5148b

Comment: Hmmmm...let me know if that solution works or not as I don't have Surface tab :(